# Angular show tooltip in svg as a div or component?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, svg

I want to show tooltips on my svg chart. On mouseover (mouseenter,mouseleave) in Angular. How can I do it? If I can use div, svg do not know 'div'. Can I use component? When I move mouse on circle I want show some information. Now I only show value. How can I show all in one div/component, when some circles are over each other. I want show all lines names with values.

```
<svg version="1.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="graph"
     aria-labelledby="title">
  <g *ngFor="let dataArray of data2.valueP; let i = index" [attr.fill]="data2.colorArray[i]">
    <g *ngFor="let data of dataArray; let k = index" >
      <circle [attr.cx]="134+(1470/dataArray.length)*k" [attr.cy]="800*(1-(dataArray[k]/data2.maxR))"
              [attr.r]="3" (mouseover)="chartHovered(dataArray[k])">{{ dataArray.length }}</circle>
      <title>{{dataArray[k] }}</title>
      <line *ngIf="800*(1-(dataArray[k+1]/data2.maxR))>0" [attr.x1]="134+(1470/dataArray.length)*k"
            [attr.y1]="800*(1-(dataArray[k]/data2.maxR))" [attr.x2]="134+(1470/dataArray.length)*(k+1)"
            [attr.y2]="800*(1-(dataArray[k+1]/data2.maxR))" style="stroke-width:2" [attr.stroke]="data2.colorArray[i]"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Thank for your advice and tips.

Comment: The simplest way is via a SVG <title> child element.

Comment: Yes, this I use now....and how to show values from other curves in the title? if the circles are over each other.

Comment: If you want to show some composite title, put the circles in a <g> and give the <g> a title child.

Comment: Please, could you send me here some example?